# Getting moment.js moment 0 in unix timestamp

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to use moment.js for similar calculations as python timedelta.

what i have trouble with is this:

```
var d = moment(0);
d
Moment {_i: 0, _f: undefined, _l: undefined, _isUTC: false, _d: Thu Jan 01 1970 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (EET)…}
_d: Thu Jan 01 1970 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (EET)
_f: undefined
_i: 0
_isUTC: false
_l: undefined
__proto__: Object
d.hours();
2
d.days();
4
```

How can i get moment timestamp equal to unix timestamp 0, cause moment(0) does not seem to give me moment where days, hours, seconds and whatnot is all 0 and which transforms to unix timestamp 0 with moment.js format 'X' ([link](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/))

In response to comments:
Usually timepickers work for picking time of certain date/day. And the value of timepicker 14:35 is usually interpreted as 14 hours and 35 minutes. You COULD use the same picker for letting user choose PERIOD (or timedelta) not TIME. Which would mean that there is 14 hours and 35 minutes between something, or something takes that time... so on...

And you can use moment.js for simulating that functionality. Because:

```
moment(0).utc().hours == 0
moment(0).utc().minutes == 0
moment(0).utc().seconds == 0
```

You can just add (or let user add) hours, minutes, seconds to choose not time but PERIOD. Or timedelta. Unfortunatley this fails, when period is longer than 24 hours. because moment(0).utc().days() equals to 4 not 0.

Not sure why this WHY is relevant, when for all reasons i can think of moment(0).utc().days() should be 0 not 4...

Comment: `var d = moment(0).utc();`  I think you need to tell moment that this "timestamp" is in UTC.

Comment: Also, why exactly are you doing `moment(0)`?

Comment: moment(0).utc().days(); still prints out 4. I explained why in question. I want to present time to user as timedelta (difference between 2 timestamps) not as certain timestamp. Python datetime.timedelta is excellent for it. I thought that i could simulate same functionality with moment.js, but so far it seems, that i cant get it working like this.

Comment: In essence moment(0) could work as timedelta, if all parts of the timestamp would be 0. But they are not.

Comment: I know nothing about `timedelta`, but what 2 timestamps are you trying to get the difference between?  Why do you think you need `moment(0)` for this?  Does this not work for you: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/? Can you show us the *actual* problem you are having?  I think this might be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Hmmm.. now THIS i can use. +1 Thanks.

Comment: I figured out why `days()` is 4 (ok, [@jeremy](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19909674/206403) did).  That's the *DAY OF THE WEEK*!  You wanted `d.date()` for the day of the month (which would actually be 1, not 0) http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/date/ ;-)

Comment: Well that moment.js diff hint helped me fix this issue in other way. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your running into issues with the time zone that moment detects you in.  If you do

```
moment(0).toISOString()
```

You should see 0s for all days etc.  You can set the time zone to UTC by doing something like

```
var a = moment(0);
a.utc();
a.toString()
```

a.toString should now display as the correct timezone.

Also, `moment(0).utc().days()` is "Wednesday" (Or whatever day currently is).